# Setting with copy warning... what am I doing wrong?

Tags: pandas, warnings, pandas-settingwithcopy-warning

I've read all kinds of documentation about this warning in Pandas. Aside from getting frustrated because I still haven't seen a case where it's not absolutely clear what is trying to be done (so the warning feels like a needless complication), I'm still getting the warning even when seemingly doing what is recommended.

Here is my original code. I'm trying to convert two columns ('A' and 'B') to DateTime.

`df[['A', 'B']] = df[['A', 'B']].apply(pd.to_datetime)`

After reading about using .loc as the preferred method, I changed to:

`df.loc[:, ['A', 'B']] = df.loc[:, ['A', 'B']].apply(pd.to_datetime)`

But I'm still getting the same warning. Would someone be kind enough to point out what I'm missing?

Comment: `df` is probably already a copy somewhere before this line.  So you need to go back and see where you made a subset and add `.copy()`

Comment: can you provide a minimal example where this happens?

Comment: if you have somewhere `df1=df`, you will have such a warning.
`df1=df.copy()` will not have this warning, - P.S. these two statements are not the same

Comment: Yes, there was an upstream step where I isolated some of the rows: `df = original_df[original_df['payment_type']==1]`. I'm guessing that's where the problem is.